# stream analytics query get error column name doesn't exist, but it does?

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure, azure-stream-analytics

When I run my query in management studio it works fine, but in a stream analytics job it throws an error: Query compilation error: Invalid column name: 'afkorting'. Column with such name does not exist..

I downloaded the input tables to check if something went wrong with uploading, but that file does have that column name (and I double checked for capital letters, miswriting etc), so how can I fix this?

This is my query:

```
; WITH Check AS

    (
    SELECT afkorting, *
     FROM Reizen RE
     LEFT JOIN Gegevens AP
     ON RE.ID = AP.code
    )

SELECT *
    FROM Check CH
    JOIN Model VM
    ON CH.afkorting = VM.Station
    WHERE VM.h_station = VM.v_station
    AND DATEPART(hour, CH.MsgReportDate) = VM.start_uur
    AND (DATEPART(minute, CH.MsgReportDate) BETWEEN VM.start_minuut AND VM.eind_minuut)
    AND DATEPART(weekday, CH.MsgReportDate) = VM.weekdag
```

Hope someone can help me!

*PROBLEM SOLVED: you need to give in all columnnames, so not SELECT * but SELECT column1, column2 and use the given prefixes of the table, in my case: AP.column1, RE.column2 etc*

Comment: Have you tried to specify columns explicitly rather than using * ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it doesn't give an error on the 'afkorting' column, but it does give the same error on the first given column and when I delete that one, it gives the same error for the column that's now given first?! I guess it's a bug then?

Comment: I don't think they support `WITH Check` in stream analytics.

Comment: You mean a cte? I shortend the cte real name to Check. But if you don't do a cte as WITH 'name' AS, how do you do a cte in stream analytics?

Comment: This is interesting, can you introduce fake first column and give it some constant value? You will not use it anyway

Comment: Problem solved! Need to write out all columnnames in CTE and use the prefixes

Comment: You could consider writing an answer with explanation, this way other people can benefit from it (instead of reading comments)

Comment: : you need to give in all columnnames, so not SELECT * but SELECT column1, column 2 and use the given prefixes of the table, in my case: AP.column1, RE.column2 etc

Comment: Welcome to SO avk.  Please write the solution as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just summarize all comments above for resolving the issue, I did some testing for Stream Query language elements `WITH`, `SELECT` & [`JOIN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn835026.aspx). Here is my result list for the issue.

1. Without `JOIN`, using column names with symbol `*` in the `WITH` scope is correct for executing on ASA.
2. With `JOIN`, it's necessary to list all column names you want without symbol `*` for executing. The reason seems to be to avoid ambiguity with column name conflict.

Answer (score 0):

you need to give in all column names, so not

`SELECT * but SELECT column1, column2`

and use the given prefixes of the table,
for example
 in my case:

```
 AP.column1, RE.column2 etc
```